# Id Starwith and .not() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done a validation to avoid special characters with the following code for all input text, however, I have input text that require having special characters. My code is as follows

```
$('.twTextinput input, .twTextinput textarea').not( $( '#txtEmailPersonal input, #txtEmailTrabajo input' )).keyup(function (){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,'');
});
```

The problem is this, I have an input text that must be within the selector .not(). Is a input text that has an id that **starts** with "iccw". I tried with this code but does not work

```
$('.twTextinput input, .twTextinput textarea').not( $( '#txtEmailPersonal input, #txtEmailTrabajo input, input[id^="iccw"]' )).keyup(function (){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,'');
});
```

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is an awfully complex way single out one special input, don't you think?

I would tend to want find all "regular" textareas or inputs into an container and use find to collect them, and then single out the other "normal" inputs.

```
$normal_input_list  = $(container).find( 'input.normal, textarea.normal' );
$special_input_list = $( '#icww' );

onKeyupNormal = function (){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,'');
};

// and now bind the handler
$normal_input_list.on( 'keyup', onKeyupNormal );
```

If there is a good reason to select as you have, then I have determined the following should work:

```
$('input, textarea').not( '#wmd-input' );
```

Specifying input and ID is redundant, as ID is already unique across the page.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack:

```
$('.twTextinput input, .twTextinput textarea').not( $( '#txtEmailPersonal input, #txtEmailTrabajo input' 
)).keyup(function (){
    if( this.id != 'iccw' ) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,'');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to control this with HTML attributes. I find it more manageable.

```
<textarea data-allowedchars="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]"><textarea>
<textarea ></textarea>

<input data-allowedchars="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]" />
<input />
```

JS

```
$("body").on("keyup", "[data-allowedchars]", 
   function(e){
       var $t = $(this),
           re = new RegExp($t.data("allowedchars"),'g');

       $t.val($t.val().replace(re, ""));
   }
);
```

Sorry this doesn't directly answer your question. It is hard to see what is wrong with your syntax without seeing the code.